What happens if I short the MISO line and SCL line?
I need some beginner level help in understanding things.
I have attached the circuit below, in the case where both the 0 Ω resistors are assembled, would I expect some communication between my controller and my SPI device?


that depends a bit on which SPI timing model you are using,  also drawing does not match the text. also sclk points wrong way.

hi yes ,thank you for your reply , so the SPI settings are as follows
CPOL =0 CPHA = 1
MSB FIRST
1Mhz Freq , 50% duty cycle

Are the pullups for I2C lines inside the EEPROM?

Bad idea.
The I²C device has no idea about the CS line and could happily desturb the data during SPI communication if the pattern on the bus was just right.
SPI usage will also violate the timing and bus driving constrains of I²C (which does NOT allow outputs to actively drive a HIGH signal) - confusing the EEPROM chips.
TL;DR Expect a lot of trouble with a circuit like this.
